# Combining "var f =" code to function as one

Tags: javascript, pdf

I wish to have two `var f =` codes function as one so that the export values from two different fields (`FMModule1` & `Ligh-Temp`) merge and display in the receiving field.

The tricky part is that I want the result to be different depending on the selected option from the dropdown (`FMModule1`). The code below would serve two different functions, where the `X` part is working fine.

The issue arises when I add the second `var f` snippet (the one with the `Y`. In other words, everything works fine without the top part (the code with the `Y` value).

My current code:

```
var f = this.getField("FMModule1").valueAsString.split("--")[2];
if (f == "Y") 
  event.value = this.getField("Light-Temp").valueAsString.split("--")[0]

var f = this.getField("FMFinish1").valueAsString.split("--")[3]
if (f == "X") 
  event.value = "";
else 
  event.value = this.getField("FMModule1").valueAsString.split("--")[0]
    + this.getField("FMFinish1").valueAsString.split("--")[0]
    + this.getField("FMAccPerf1").valueAsString.split("--")[0];
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. Is the problem that you’re trying to declare `f` twice? Remove the second `var` (which should be `let` anyway, most likely) or name it something different?

Comment: Tangential: get those two valueAsString values once; makes the rest easier to read, imo.

Answer (score -1):

If i didn't understand wrong, you are trying to check it in an order. Howewer the problem is it checks the first condition which is `f === "Y"` either this condition is true or false, it continues executing code and checks for `f === "X"` if false, it goes to `else` and assigns the value inside `else` statement.

The solution to this problem is adding `else if` to the second condition check.
After doing that your code should look like this:

```
var f = this.getField("FMModule1").valueAsString.split("--")[2];
if (f == "Y") 
  event.value = this.getField("Light-Temp").valueAsString.split("--")[0]

var f = this.getField("FMFinish1").valueAsString.split("--")[3]
else if (f == "X") // add else here.
  event.value = "";
else 
  event.value = this.getField("FMModule1").valueAsString.split("--")[0]
    + this.getField("FMFinish1").valueAsString.split("--")[0]
    + this.getField("FMAccPerf1").valueAsString.split("--")[0];
```

Comment: You know this script bombs with an error, right?

Comment: Thank you. Below is what ended up working perfectly: 
var y = this.getField("FMModule1").valueAsString.split("--")[2];

var z = this.getField("FMModule1").valueAsString.split("--")[2];

var x = this.getField("FMFinish1").valueAsString.split("--")[3]
if (x=="X") event.value = "";

else 

if (y=="Y")
event.value =
this.getField("Light-Temp").valueAsString.split("--")[0]
+ this.getField("FMModule1").valueAsString.split("--")[0]
+ this.getField("FMFinish1").valueAsString.split("--")[0]
+ this.getField("FMAccPerf1").valueAsString.split("--")[0];

if (z=="Z")
event.value = .......